# Reference type return function: how to return (optional) object

Tags: c++, reference

I've a multithreaded C++ application that could call from any thread a function like the following, to get an Object from a list/vector.

```
class GlobalClass{
public:
     MyObject* GlobalClass::getObject(int index) const
     {
          /* mutex lock & unlock */

          if (m_list.hasValueAt(index))
              return m_list[index];
          else
              return 0;
     }
List<MyObject*> m_list;
};

//Thread function
MyObject* obj = globalClass->getObject(0);
if (!obj) return;
obj->doSomething();
```

*Note: the scope here is to understand some best practice related to function returns by reference, value or pointer, so forgive some pseudo-code or missing declarations (I make use of lock/unlock, `GlobalClass` is a global singleton, etc...).*

The issue here is that if the `MyObject` at that index in deleted inside `GlobalClass`, at a certain point I'm using a bad pointer (`obj`).

So I was thinking about returning **a copy** of the oject:

```
     MyObject GlobalClass::getObject(int index) const
     {
          /* mutex lock & unlock */

          if (m_list.hasValueAt(index))
              return MyObject(*m_list[index]);
          else
              return MyObject();
     }
```

The issue here is that the object (`MyObject`) being returned is a large enough object that returning a copy is not efficient.

Finally, I would like to return **a reference** to that object (better a const reference):

```
     const MyObject& GlobalClass::getObject(int index) const
     {
          /* mutex lock & unlock */

          if (m_list.hasValueAt(index))
              return *m_list[index];
          else{
              MyObject* obj = new MyObject();
              return *obj ;
          }
     }
```

Considering that my list couldn't cointain the object at that index, I'm introducing a memory leak.

What's the best solution to deal with this?
Must I fall back in returning a copy even if is less efficient or is there something I'm missing in returning a reference?

Comment: Use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: Oh and the third version of your program (returning a reference) still have the problem you mention for the first, you can return a reference to an object that is later deleted and making the reference invalid.

Comment: Use a [weak pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). That is make your vector a vector of `shared_ptr` and then return a `weak_ptr`. If some other thread deletes the original object you can test for that on your weak_ptr object. And weak pointers copy reasonably efficiently

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I did a test (http://cpp.sh/7k5t2) to understand the case, and it seems the reference is still value after deletion. What I'm missing?

Comment: The reference *isn't* valid. It's like a pointer to a deleted object, you can still dereference the pointer but it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple choices:

1. Use a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if "Get" pass the owning of the object to the caller. This way the object cannot get out of scope. Of course the caller is unaware when it happens.
2. Use a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). This has the same meaning of 1., but the ptr can be reset. In this case the caller can detect if the object was deleted.
3. Use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as suggested in a comment, and return a copy or a reference. The use of a reference type as argument of optional doesn't avoid the problem of the object being deleted so the reference can become invalid as well. A copy would avoid this, but it may be too expensive, as said.

Reading through the lines, you seems to suggest that the caller will use the pointer immediately after the call, and for a limited span of time. So 1. and 2. are equivalent and seems to fit your needs.

See [this introduction to smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) for more details.

Comment: Also could be an optional reference wrapper.

Comment: Yes, but if the pointed object is deleted, the reference will become invalid. So perhaps the smart pointer approach seems to avoid this.

Comment: It's for option 3, it doesn't have to be a copy if OP knows about the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Yes, but the OP states it's a multithreaded program, so I assume it is not known if the objects are used in the same or in different threads.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid copying the object, there are only two possible cases:

1. The `m_list` entry that is returned by `getObject` is/can be deleted concurrently by another thread. If you don't copy that object beforehand, there is nothing you can do within `getObject` to prevent another thread from suddenly having a reference/pointer dangle. However, you could make each entry of `m_list` be a `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>` and return that directly. The memory management will happen automatically (but beware of the potential overhead in the reference counting of `shared_ptr`, as well as the possibility of deadlocks).
2. You have (or add) some mechanism to ensure that objects can only be deleted from `m_list` if no other thread currently holds some pointer/reference to them. This very much depends on your algorithm, but it might e.g. be possible to mark objects for deletion only and then delete them later in a synchronous section.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues seems to stem from the fact that your program is multithreaded - another way forward (and for raw pointer or the `std::optional` reference returning version: only way forward, perhaps short of a complete redesign), is that you need to expose the mutex to outside the function scope to accomplish what you need. This you can accomplish in multiple ways, however the most simple way to illustrate this is the following:

```
/*mutex lock*/
const MyObject& obj = globalClass.get(index);
/*do stuff with obj*/
/*mutex unlock*/
```